# Most triangles formed by three triangles

Tags: geometry

What is the maximum number of triangles you can form by drawing three triangles on a piece of paper?

Good luck!

Comment: Do all the sides have to be *drawn* or can we use the sides of the paper? Is the paper flat?

Comment: all sides need to be drawn and the paper is flat (as usual).

Comment: I tried to find a proven result about this, but it's very hard to figure out search keywords. The number of results on "maximum triangles" is astonishing. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've managed to get

> 30 triangles

As follows

> [image]

The trick here is

> To make the three triangles maximally intersecting. I'm not sure if this is optimal here though.

Counting

> Note here that each red kite region as shown yields two large triangles and two small triangles. Going around the outer vertices we see that the large triangles are distinct so there are 18 of them but the small triangles are each counted twice so there are 9 of them and then we add the three original triangles to get 30.
>  [image]

Comment: Nice answer. This could be our winner...

Comment: This seems to be the maximum, ran python script on 100 000 random configurations, no more than 30.

Comment: Let's try this possible proof outline again. In the diagram of this answer, each side of a triangle crosses exactly two sides from each of the other two triangles. This results in a total of eighteen crossing points, plus the original nine big triangle vertexes, or 27 points. Every one of the 30 big and small triangles, obviously, has three of these 27 points as its vertices. To add more triangles, you either need more points for vertices -- impossible, you can't have a side cross another side in the same triangle, nor have a side cross all 3 sides of the other triangle ...

Comment: ... or else you need to reshape the non-triangle shapes in the diagram (the nonagon and quadrialterals) to be triangles. That part seems impossible ... still working on it.

Comment: Here we go. Turning a quadrialteral into a triangle means making one of its vertices coincide with **two** others (try it; you can't make it just be one). This means eliminating one triangle completely, and also making two other triangles coincide, for a net loss of two triangles. Turning the nonagon into a triangle would require even more lossage. This isn't airtight, but I think it's convincing.

Comment: Playground: https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/sv7kqwbn

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I would *love* to see your python script.

Comment: @RossPresser You seem to have gotten quite far with this proof. Did you want to post the construction as another answer?

Comment: @RossPresser https://github.com/megabyte0/python/blob/master/puzzling/100629/100629.py

Answer (score 6):

This might not be optimal, but its the best one I could find:

> It has 18 triangles.

> [image]

here are some of the triangles highlighted for clarity

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

> and then, of course, the 3 original triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Every larger distinct triangle has a side with a different colour and a number adjacent to that triangle. The smaller distinct triangles have a number inside them, except in cases where the triangle is very small, in which case the number is adjacent to the triangle. The three overlapping triangles generate twenty-four distinct triangles.

[image: tri]

Comment: The diagram seems identical to hexomimo answer, but the triangle count is different.